# asp.net mvc 4: simplemembership - WebSecurity.Login fails when the user is not confirmed

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

By default, WebSecurity.Login method returns false when the user is not confirmed.
How can I make it work regardless of the user confirmation status?

Answer (score 1):

If confirmation is not important to you then when you call CreateUserAndAccount() or CreateAccount() make sure you pass requireConfirmationToken as false.

That way once the account is created it will not require confirmation and Login() should work with the right credentials.

EDIT: The general need for confirmation is to make sure you have a reliable means of communication with the user (like an email address) if the user has forgotten their password. Without confirmation you will not have this "confirmed" means of communication.
You can also try flipping bits in the webpages_Membership database (IsConfirmed == 1) but I wouldn't recommend that either.

Comment: As you said I wouldn't recommend flipping the bits - if you need to, you should probably not use the confirmation mechanism. Instead, just pass `false` for `requireConfirmationToken` and new users are automatically confirmed.

Comment: I need to verify user's email address, so confirmation is important to me. But when I pass requireConfirmationToken: true in CreateUserAndAccount(), the created user can't login.
In my site, users should be able to log in without verifying their email(like many other websites).